# Ubuntu server has two ip addresses not sure why

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

My Ubuntu server appears to have two ip addresses (192.168.0.108 and 192.168.0.109) but I haven't been able to get rid of the one.

Devices and setup:

- TP-LINK AX1500 Router (handles dhcp, DNS redirected to pihole).
- Ubuntu Server 20.04

  - Pihole installed and running as the DNS, blocking currently disabled. TP-LINK doesn't do hostname resolution so I use Pihole to create a Local DNS record so that all devices can use the domain/hostname instead of the servers ip.

What I see from `ip addr show`

```
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:a3:f3:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.109/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 7100sec preferred_lft 7100sec
    inet 192.168.0.108/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7285:c2ff:fea3:f3fc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When running this command it does remove the 109 temporarily but it comes right back after reboot. I also can't connect to the server remotely anymore as other devices still think it is 109.

```
ip address del 192.168.0.109/24 dev eno1
```

What I see in /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.conf

```yml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
```

What I see in /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
#clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu
```

What I see in /etc/network/interfaces (empty)

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

I modified the /etc/pihole/setupVars.conf which did have 109 as the IPV4_ADDRESS and set it to 108 but 109 still didn't go away after reboot.

```
PIHOLE_INTERFACE=eno1
IPV4_ADDRESS=192.168.0.108/24
IPV6_ADDRESS=
```

Also, weird that in the TP-LINK router interface seems to show the server with different addresses in different parts of the UI. In the Network Map -> Clients list it shows the server as being 108. However, in the Advanced -> Network -> DHCP Server -> DHCP Client List it shows the server as being 109.

I'm lost for what to do next and how to fix the server having two ip addresses.

Comment: a WiFi card as well as a wired connection?

Comment: The motherboard seems to support WiFi though I don't use it, the server is connected to the router with a cat5 cable. https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z370M-ITXac/index.asp

Running `lshw` does show a `description: Wireless interface
product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer fixed my issue. Instead of trying to delete 109, I instead deleted 108 (secondary) after disabling and stopping dhcpcd.

```
update-rc.d dhcpcd disable
service dhcpcd stop
ip addr del 192.168.0.108/24 dev eno1
```

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/33910